# Replacing a url with sed, that contains ampersands

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have replaced urls in the past using sed with no problem before. However, this url imparticular is giving me trouble. It has quite a few ampersands and I need to replace them. How would I go about doing that?

```
sed -i.bak "s#<string>https://www.url1toreplace.com?blah=1234585474738743874386328764287364238746283764287346872364fN&amp;blah=Y&amp;blah=%2Fwebapp%2Fwcs%2Fblahblah%2Fblah%2Fen%2Fblahahah%3Fblah%3e212e123152%26cm_mmc%3DBLAH-_-BLAH-_-Null-_-Null</string>#<string>https://www.urltoreplace.com/blah/blah/blah/blah/en/blah?blah=129i312093132&cm_mmc=BLAH-_-BLAH-_-Null-_-Null</string>#g" path/to/xml/file
```

My problem is that it's not fully replacing the url. How do I escape the ampersands so I can successfully replace www.url1toreplace.com with www.urltoreplace.com and everything that follows?

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean by `replace ... **everything that follows**`; at a minimum could you provide an example of actual data, both the before and after values

Comment: Hi. Sorry if that was not clear. I'm looking to replace <string>https://www.url1toreplace.com?blah=1234585474738743874386328764287364238746283764287346872364fN&amp;blah=Y&amp;blah=%2Fwebapp%2Fwcs%2Fblahblah%2Fblah%2Fen%2Fblahahah%3Fblah%3e212e123152%26cm_mmc%3DBLAH-_-BLAH-_-Null-_-Null</string> with <string>https://www.urltoreplace.com/blah/blah/blah/blah/en/blah?blah=129i312093132&cm_mmc=BLAH-_-BLAH-_-Null-_-Null</string>

Comment: I guess try running the command I provided in the question. Does it work for you?

Comment: 1) don't have the xmlfile you're querying; 2) can't tell if the excessive `blah`'s are part of the actual data or an attempt to mask the real data; at this point I'm assuming you want to replace **everything** ... URL and all parameters ... between `<string>https://www.` and `</string>`

Answer (score 3):

In the replacement text, you need to escape `&`.

For example, *without* the escape, the whole of the original match is substituted in for each `&`:

```
$ echo '&amp;' | sed 's#&amp;#a & b & c#'
a &amp; b &amp; c
```

With the escape, `\&`, `&` is treated as an ordinary character:

```
$ echo '&amp;' | sed 's#&amp;#a \& b \& c#'
a & b & c
```

#### Your example

Let's take this test file:

```
$ cat file
<string>https://www.url1toreplace.com?blah=1234585474738743874386328764287364238746283764287346872364fN&amp;blah=Y&amp;blah=%2Fwebapp%2Fwcs%2Fblahblah%2Fblah%2Fen%2Fblahahah%3Fblah%3e212e123152%26cm_mmc%3DBLAH-_-BLAH-_-Null-_-Null</string>
```

And run the original command:

```
$ sed "s#<string>https://www.url1toreplace.com?blah=1234585474738743874386328764287364238746283764287346872364fN&amp;blah=Y&amp;blah=%2Fwebapp%2Fwcs%2Fblahblah%2Fblah%2Fen%2Fblahahah%3Fblah%3e212e123152%26cm_mmc%3DBLAH-_-BLAH-_-Null-_-Null</string>#<string>https://www.urltoreplace.com/blah/blah/blah/blah/en/blah?blah=129i312093132\&cm_mmc=BLAH-_-BLAH-_-Null-_-Null</string>#g" file
<string>https://www.urltoreplace.com/blah/blah/blah/blah/en/blah?blah=129i312093132&cm_mmc=BLAH-_-BLAH-_-Null-_-Null</string>
```

The above command fails.  If we escape the `&`, however, we get:

```
$ sed 's#<string>https://www.url1toreplace.com?blah=1234585474738743874386328764287364238746283764287346872364fN&amp;blah=Y&amp;blah=%2Fwebapp%2Fwcs%2Fblahblah%2Fblah%2Fen%2Fblahahah%3Fblah%3e212e123152%26cm_mmc%3DBLAH-_-BLAH-_-Null-_-Null</string>#<string>https://www.urltoreplace.com/blah/blah/blah/blah/en/blah?blah=129i312093132\&cm_mmc=BLAH-_-BLAH-_-Null-_-Null</string>#g' file
<string>https://www.urltoreplace.com/blah/blah/blah/blah/en/blah?blah=129i312093132&cm_mmc=BLAH-_-BLAH-_-Null-_-Null</string>
```

This succeeds: the `&` in the replacement string successfully appears in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Sample data file:

```
$ cat xfile
<string>https://www.old.home.com?x=123&amp;y=abc&amp;z=ABC_mmc%3D</string>
```

Desired output:

```
<string>https://www.new.home.biz?A=XYZ&amp;B=123&amp;C=987_jjj%2XD</string>
```

As John1024's already pointed out, if a `sed` replacement string contains `&`'s, the `&`'s have to be escaped (`\&`) (because `&` has a special meaning to `sed`).

Hmmmm, but that could be a major pain in the keister if ya gotta go through and (manually?) change all `sed` replacement patterns from `&` to `\&`.   But this replacement can be automated with a few minor assumptions ...

Assumptions:

- search and replace patterns can be stored in variables `before` and `after`, respectively (actually, only the `after` variable is needed for this idea to work, but for this example I'll use `before` and `after` variables)
- `before` and `after` contain normal strings w/out any special escapes
- your version of `bash` supports character replacement via the `${var// /}` construct

Apply escapes to the `after` variable on the fly:

```
$ before='old.home.com?x=123&amp;y=abc&amp;z=ABC_mmc%3D'

$ after='new.home.biz?A=XYZ&amp;B=123&amp;C=987_jjj%2XD'

$ sed "s#${before}#${after//\&/\\\&}#g" xfile

<string>https://www.new.home.biz?A=XYZ&amp;B=123&amp;C=987_jjj%2XD</string>
```

- `${after//\&/\\\&}` : in the `after` variable, replace all occurrences of `&` with `\&`

This eliminates the need to go through and manually escape all occurrences of `&` in the replacement string.

Comment: Hmmm.. you're right. It would be a pain in the keister doing that manually! I thought about looping individual characters in the sting and replacing it that way.. but that's resource intensive. My examples have backslash inside them `/` how would `${var// /}` construct you suggested work with that?

Comment: The `//` and `/` are predefined delimiters so all you would need to do is escape your search/replace patterns (as needed), eg:  `x='a/c' ; echo ${x//\//X} => aXc ; x='a\c' ; echo ${x//\\/X} => aXc`